# Validate when array contains specific value

Tags: joi

I want to use an rule like, but I'm having some issues to fullfill the "is" rule for the when condition on Joi validation library.

```
let schema = {
    field1: Joi.array().items(Joi.string().valid('v1', 'v2')),
    field2: Joi.when("field1", {
        is: // if field1 contains at least 'v1',
        then: Joi.object().keys(...),
        otherwise: Joi.forbidden()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array.items` by listing all allowed types. If a given type is `.required()` then there must be a matching item in the array:
[joi API reference](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v13.1.2/API.md#arrayitemstype)

```
let schema = {
    field1: Joi.array().items(Joi.string().valid('v1', 'v2')),
    field2: Joi.when("field1", {
        is: Joi.array().items(Joi.string().valid('v1').required(), Joi.string().valid('v2'))
        then: Joi.object().keys(...),
        otherwise: Joi.forbidden()
    }
}
```